# how to make before: and after: and box-sizing:border-box work in ie7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a website built with twitter bootstrap 3 which works on all browsers other than IE7.

It's not reading pseudo classes such as `before:`, `after:` and `box-sizing: border-box`.

Is there anyway I can get IE7 to read this code?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/

Comment: This only mentions support for browser, not a solution. Been trying to find out all day as well as trying different solutions. Im going MADD!

Answer (score 0):

http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/test/index.html

**IE7.js** supports the following properties

```
Property    Comments    Test
background-attachment   support fixed positioning   html
background-image    PNG alpha transparency (IE5.5+) html
bottom  height implied if top is supplied   html
cursor  support pointer for IE5.x   html
display convert list-item to block for IE5.x    
font-size   fix named font sizes (IE5.x)    html
margin  support auto (IE5.x)    html
max-height      html
max-width       html
min-height  implemented for IE5 html
min-width       html
overflow    support overflow:visible    html
position    support fixed positioning   html
right   width implied if left is supplied   html
```

**IE8.js** supports the following:

```
Selector    Comments    Test
::after     html
::before        html
:active     html
:focus      html
:lang()     html
CSS Properties

Property    Comments    Test
border-spacing  HTML tables only    html
box-sizing  content-box (assumed)   html
content Supports the use of attr() and url()    html
property: inherit   Support for inherited property values   html
```

Comment: I tried borderBox.js plugin but again, no luck. This is doing my head in.